# Wires for home theater system

Tags: audio, wiring

May I use two 16 gauge insulated wire in lieu of one 14 gauge wire for the speakers of a home theater system? Thicker wire is better for the quality of sound (or so do they say). So do two 16 gauge insulated wires provide the same quality of sound as one 14 gauge wire?

Comment: "Thinker wire is better for the quality of sound." [citation needed]

Comment: so two thinner wires do not provide the equivalent of a thicker wire for sound quality?

Comment: Sound quality is independent of the thickness of the wires. Sound *volume* may not be.

Comment: But surely thinner wire contains less oxygen (as there's less room for it), and as we all know less oxygen makes for better sound, doesn't it? So the sellers of oxygen-free copper wires want us to believe.  So wouldn't the sound quality *increase* with smaller wires?

Comment: I think Majenko is kidding. Forget about oxygen. Oxygen free wire is a scam.

But it is worthwhile to keep the resistance of the wire low. Two 16 gauge wires in parallel will be slightly lower in resistance than one 14 gauge, so go for it.

Comment: I understand about sound quality.  Thank you guys for help. How about for the power (sound volume)?  Home theaters have about 1000 watts.  How is two 16 gauge wire in lieu of one 14 gauge wire in regards to that?

Comment: Even if your wire has enough oxygen in it to make it look like the inside of an Aero bar it still only affects resistance, and that is *still* not a major factor in audio quality.

Comment: The reason low resistance is (said to be) important for sound quality is that resistance in the cables reduces the damping factor of the amplifier ie once the speaker cone/voice coil is moving, it acts as a generator and produces a back-emf; the lower the resistance, the better the momentum of the speaker cone can be braked by the load represented by the amp, so the movement of the cone more faithfully follows the signal.

Comment: @Romeo - Ignore these guys. You've tapped into a deep well of frustration about hifi woo. As to how much wire you need, here's a start.  Find out the impedance of each speaker (maybe 8 ohms, maybe less). Now find the length of the wire running from the amp to that speaker and double it. You can find the ohms/ft for a given gauge wire - use this to find the gauge that produces a wire resistance less than 1/10 the speaker impedance, or less than 1/100 if you're feeling picky. And yes, running two thin in parallel is a good as one thick, as long as the total resistance is the same or less.

Comment: See [this related question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/110901/11683).

Comment: I cannot imagine being in a typical home theater room with 1000 Watts actually delivered to the speakers. This is a side comment. Nothing to do with the question or answer.

Comment: @mkeith I can, but my imagination is very warped. I see blood. Lots of blood...  dripping... dripping...

Answer (score 3):

It is worthwhile to keep the resistance of the wire low. Two 16 gauge wires in parallel will be slightly lower in resistance than one 14 gauge wire. So if you have some reason to believe that 14 gauge is good, two 16 gauge will be just as good.